# SQL For each value from a table, execute a query on another table depending on that value

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have two simple tables:

Table #1 `apples_consumption`

| report_date | apples_consumed |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| 2022-02-01 | 7 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2 |

Table #2 `hotel_visitors`

| visitor_id | check_in_date | check_out_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | NULL |
| 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL |
| 4 | 2022-03-01 | NULL |

My purpose is to get a table which shows the ratio between number of visitors in the hotel to number of apples consumed by that time.

For the example above the desired query output should look like this:

| report_date | visitors_count | apples_consumed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 -->(visitors #1, #2) | 5 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 -->(visitors #1, #2, #3) | 7 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 -->(visitors #2, #3, #4) | 2 |

If I were to write a solution to this task using code I would go over each `report_date` from the `apples_consumption` table and count how many visitors have a lower/equal `check_in_date` than that `report_date` and also have a `check_out_date` = NULL or `check_out_date` greater/equal than that `report_date`

I came up with this query:

```sql
select
    ac.report_date,
    ac.apples_consumed,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from hotel_visitors hv 
        where 
            hv.check_in_date <= ac.report_date and 
            (hv.check_out_date is null or hv.check_out_date >= ac.report_date
    ) as visitors_count
from
    apples_consumptions ac
order by
    ac.report_date
```

The query above works but it is very inefficient (I can see its relatively long execution time for larger datasets and by the way its written [it runs the inner count(*) query for as many rows as the outer `apples_consuptions` table has)

I am looking for a more efficient way to achieve this result and your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very rarely a good idea to put a subselect in your select list.

Join your tables and then use an aggregate count:

```
select a.report_date, count(v.visitor_id) as visitors_count, a.apples_consumed
  from apples_consumption a
       left join hotel_visitors v
         on a.report_date 
              between v.check_in_date 
                and coalesce(v.check_out_date, '9999-12-31')
 group by a.report_date, a.apples_consumed
 order by a.report_date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c4c2e363b165a8ad1608103f8e659a6e)*